# Why is this block of haml code giving 'syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

```
= tabs_tag(:open_tabs => { :id => "menu" }) do |tab| 
  - menu_tabs.each do |menu_tab|
    - if !menu_tab.only_if.nil?
      - if menu_tab.only_if.call
        = tab.send menu_tab.tab_name, menu_tab.display_name, menu_tab.path, :span => "arrow-down"
          - if !menu_tab.child_elements.blank?
            %ul
            - menu_tab.child_elements.each do |child_tab|
              %li
                =link_to child_tab.display_name, child_tab.path
    - else
      = tab.send menu_tab.tab_name, menu_tab.display_name, menu_tab.path
```

The error message is

```
app/views/menu_builder/_tab_view.html.haml:15: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting keyword_end
app/views/menu_builder/_tab_view.html.haml:21: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end
```

(btw the line numbers are wrong too, I don't know if this is a haml thing)

I have checked the indentation and everything should be correct, and that else should correspond to if !menu_tab.only_if.nil?, so I don't understand why this error message is appearing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing it's because you're doing this:

```
= tabs_tag(:open_tabs => { :id => "menu" }) do |tab|
```

and

```
= tab.send menu_tab.tab_name, menu_tab.display_name, menu_tab.path, :span => "arrow-down"
```

and then nesting content under that which is illegal in HAML.  You get the same error when you try to do:

```
= render :partial => "some/view", :locals => { :local_var => @var }
  - if something
    -# do something
```

HAML will choke on that since it doesn't know how to render the `if` statement within the partial file (based on spacing, location of the if statement within it, etc.).  Same thing applies with other code helpers like the tabs you're using.